# Multiple errors on _Layout.cshtml in ASP Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

I have an ASP Core application.  It builds and runs without any problems but Visual Studio is showing lots of errors:

```
| Severity  |  Code    |  Description                                                                                                                   |    Project File                  |
|-----------|----------|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|----------------------------------|
| Error     |  CS0234  |  The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)           |    1_Views_Shared__Layout.cshtml |
| Error     |  CS0234  |  The type or namespace name 'Helpers' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)    |    1_Views_Shared__Layout.cshtml |
| Error     |  CS0234  |  The type or namespace name 'WebPages' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)   |    1_Views_Shared__Layout.cshtml |
| Error     |  CS0234  |  The type or namespace name 'WebPages' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)   |    1_Views_Shared__Layout.cshtml |
| Error     |  CS0234  |  The type or namespace name 'WebPages' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)   |    1_Views_Shared__Layout.cshtml |
| Error     |  CS0115  |  '_Page_Views_Shared__Layout_cshtml.Execute()': no suitable method found to override                                           |    1_Views_Shared__Layout.cshtml | 
| Error     |  CS0103  |  The name 'Context' does not exist in the current context                                                                      |    1_Views_Shared__Layout.cshtml |
| Error     |  CS0103  |  The name 'ViewData' does not exist in the current context                                                                     |    1_Views_Shared__Layout.cshtml |
```

The `_Layout.cshtml` file is the default one:

```razor
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>BanksySan @ViewData["Title"]</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>

</div>
</body>
```

The only think *different* about this project is that it's been built up from a console application, rather than via the web template.

I have the following package references:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.3" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor" Version="1.1.3" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" Version="1.1.2" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.2" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="1.1.1" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="1.1.1" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="1.1.2" />
   <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="10.0.2" />
   <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.3.1" />
   <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.2.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Due to fact that the Core MVC packages added in a console app project, seems that Intellisense missed something important when defining auto-completion for namespaces. Check if the condition similar as this: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4462.

Answer (score 0):

This to me is usually the case when Visual Studio was not able to load the basic require package such as `system`

A) try to clean do a `dotnet restore` on the project folder
B) if that didn't work clean nuget cache folder and run again
C) Close visual studio and reboot and clean again. it is also possible you have a zombie process that is still running that is not allowing visual studio to to access its temporary folder.
D) copy project to new path (git clone if possible) and to a fresh `dotnet restore`

I even had this error in Ride and above four helped me to get rid of it.

I hope it helps
Cheers